# Table to matrix in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table storing matrix information in the format:

```
CREATE TABLE "column" (
  id         serial primary key,
  name       varchar
);

CREATE TABLE matrix (
  id         serial primary key,
  column_id  integer references "column",
  "row"      integer,
  data       varchar
);
```

With sample data:

```
INSERT INTO "column"(name) VALUES ('column1'), ('column2'), ('column3'), ('column4'), ('column5');
INSERT INTO matrix(column_id, "row", data) VALUES (1, 1, '1, 1'), (1, 2, '1, 2'), (1, 3, '1, 3'), (1, 4, '1, 4'), (1, 5, '1, 5'), (2, 1, '2, 1'), (2, 2, '2, 2'), (2, 3, '2, 3'), (2, 4, '2, 4'), (2, 5, '2, 5'), (3, 1, '3, 1'), (3, 2, '3, 2'), (3, 3, '3, 3'), (3, 4, '3, 4'), (3, 5, '3, 5');
```

What is the most efficient way to represent it in the form of matrix?

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5
-----------------------------------------------
1, 1    | 1, 2    | 1, 3    | 1, 4    | 1, 5
2, 1    | 2, 2    | 2, 3    | 2, 4    | 2, 5
3, 1    | 1, 2    | 3, 3    | 3, 4    | 3, 5
```

Comment: Does it have to be pure SQL? Because this is the representation data you want to change. That's not something the database layer should do, but something the business or presentation layer of your application should do.

Comment: Your DDL probably won't work due to use of reserved words.  Please post the actual SQL you used to create your tables as well as sample data.

Comment: @sharpcloud This have to be SQL as I need to query the matrix later.

Comment: @Aleks Please look at the updated question

Comment: You seem to want a crosstab of some sort.  Depending on the version of postgres you're using, it may already be built in.  Have a look at the [`crosstab` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html).

Comment: @AleksG Might be worth posting that as an answer. Please try to link to the /current/ version of the documentation rather than /9.1/ or /9.2/ or whatever, it makes sure stale links don't accumulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a crosstab of some sort. Depending on the version of postgres you're using, it may already be built in. If I'm correct, it's built in from version 9.0 and you can add a crosstab module in version 8.4.

Have a look at the [`crosstab` function documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) for more info.